# do not understand two lines of code from Python

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I do not understand the `quite_program = False` and `quite_program = True`. What do they mean? For this code, I think it will execute the code chunk, `while not quit_program` but I do not know how to understand it. It means if quit_program is not False? I kind of confuse and thanks so much for your help.

```
def print_menu():
    print("Today's Menu:")
    print('   1) Gumbo')
    print('   2) Jambalaya')
    print('   3) Quit\n')

quit_program = False

while not quit_program :
    print_menu()
    choice = int(input('Enter choice: '))
    if choice == 3 :
        print('Goodbye')
        quit_program = True
    else :
        print('Order: ', end='')
        if choice == 1 :
            print('Gumbo')
        elif choice == 2 :
            print('Jambalaya')
        print()
```

Comment: `while not quit_program:` means "do this while `quit_program` is not true" (i.e. false).  So setting `quit_program = True` means the loop will not repeat.

Comment: However, it would be simpler to remove `quit_program` altogether, do `while True:` instead of `while not quit_program:`, and do `break` instead of `quit_program = True`.

Comment: http://cs.uky.edu/~keen/115/reading/flags-py.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, `quit_program` is used to stop the execution of the program as desired. When checking `while` loop condition initially `quit_program = False` then `not quit_program` gives `True`.

The while loop keeps executing until the `quit_program = True`. If `quit_program = True` then `not quit_program` gives `False` and then `while` loop will ends the execution(running). It means this `while` loop ends only if the `choice == 3` condition is `True`.

Therefore, your program is executing(running) until you give the `input` as 3.

Answer (score 1):

The variable quit_program = False is defined so that when the code reaches the while loop and checks if the condition is True, it enters the loop (because not False = True).
Once inside the loop, it will continue running and checking for this condition every time it starts. If quit_program is changed to True, then the next time it checks the condition at the start of the while loop, it will determine it is False (not True = False) and skip the loop.
Since there is no more code after the loop, the program ends normally.

Answer (score 0):

that's pretty simple..just like in any other programming language like C , CPP, JAVA...we often use 'flag' right?...BIngoo ...so just like that here they've made use of the 'quit_program' boolean type variable..
clearly:

```
while not quit_program :
```

means in a while loop there's also a 'not' that means whenever the condition satisfies its going to return false...so while not quit_program(quit_program is false ..so it returns true-> you get to enter the loop..there you go on printing the stuff in the

```
def print_menu():
```

cool?
so next on, the code goes on executing next set of lines in the code->

```
choice = int(input('Enter choice: '))
if choice == 3 :
    print('Goodbye')
```

after this, the quit_program if set to **true**!!! here's the catch-> from now on->>> **while not quit_program :** will be returning False!!